# CSS - prevent menu from breaking onto second line

Tags: css, responsive-design, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The menu breaks unto a second line when the browser is at about 1180 width. How can I prevent it from doing that?

http://goo.gl/5UpJSv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change the breakpoint for the burger menu to 1200px or you could increase the width of the container:

```
.container {
    max-width: 1140px;
}
```

Comment: I can't find a burger menu anywhere in the css.

Comment: You confused me with burger menu but the container adjustment worked like a charm.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Well, I thought it worked but the last menu item is still jumping down.  Would you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your breakpoint sets the `.contaner` div-s width to 970px. Now you have wo options:

1. Apply the hamburger menu on this layout (not just the lower resolutions).
2. Edit the structure a little: smaller margins, smaller padding, smaller font size.

Answer (score 0):

Hamburger menus are the ones that you have used with a button to show the navigation once the breakpoint hits 1100px on your site. Its called a hamburger menu because of the 3 horizontal lines on top of each other.

As DNReNTi says you could do this but to keep your chosen layout and, preferably, you can either change your breakpoint to be more forgiving or apply the following style changes:

```
.cap-header-fixed .menu > li, .cap-primary-menu .menu > li {
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 8px;
}
```

Also note, you have set menu icon (hamburger menu) to appear (display:block;) at @media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) and (min-width: 0px) and the main menu to display at @media (min-width: 1100px). Change this to 1101px or you will find at 1100px both the hamburger and desktop menus will both be displayed.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I see, I guess my question should have been how to change the breakpoint to be more forgiving? I don't want to display the hamburger menu at that width. I want the primary menu to show still but just not jump down to a second line.

Comment: Thats why I gave the option to edit the CSS. If you change it to what I put above it will remain on 1 line right the way to where the breakpoint is.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. [1] the last menu item still jumped down to the second line. [2] I need the menu to stay full width otherwise it looks funny :/